# Can I restrict the usage of Cognitive Services API keys by some conditions?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

In Google Cloud platform, developers can restrict the usage of API keys by some conditions.

For example,

- HTTP referrers
- IP Addresses
- Apps

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys
https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/common/images/create-api-key.png?hl=ja

I'm wondering whether the developers can restrict Azure's API keys (i.e. Cognitive Services) like GCP's case.

Answer (score 1):

I think it varies by service, but one workaround is that you can create an API that consumes the Cognitive Services API and on that API (The one you create) you can restrict usage of Keys by condition

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies

Also, it depends on your scenario and what are you trying to achieve. You can look up the valet-key pattern
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/valet-key

Comment: Thank you for your comment, SaadK.

Strictly, it'a bit different solution for my case.

When I want to use Congtive Sercvices's API key, develop some web applications and want to protect the key from robberies, GCP's way seems simple and looks good to me.

To hide API key, using Azure Function is the one way, and also your comment is the one way.

Anyway thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: Oh you are looking to secure API keys, then use Azure Key Vault 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis